# How do I fix "file can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer" error?

Tags: xcode, macos

I've published a simple text editing app in the macOS App Store. However, when users select a text file in Finder, choose to "Open with" my app, and double-click the file, they get:

[image: File can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer]

In Xcode I have checked "Automatically manage signing" and in Capabilities I have App Sandbox turned on and "User Selected File" set to Read/Write.

I'm trying to fix this for all users not just on my system.

Comment: Register your file type with Document Types under Info.  If you are trying to open text or txt with your application, you shouldn't, though.

Comment: Is this due to the problem I describe in my answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251205/why-is-osx-telling-me-i-cant-open-a-document-from-an-unidentified-developer/251242#251242)? If so, it's due to the way "Open with" works, not a problem with your app.

Comment: @ElTomato I'm trying to open text files.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, the question and answer you link explains it exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error did not have to do with my app, but instead applies to any app and the way "Open with" interacts with Gatekeeper on macOS.

Further details can be found in a discussion about [why macOS says I can't open a document from an unidentified developer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251205/why-is-osx-telling-me-i-cant-open-a-document-from-an-unidentified-developer/251242#251242).